# How to integrate cy.visit(local vs stage url) in a CI environment?

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, cypress

I have a test suite that opens a local url before making a bunch of assertions on some DOM elements.

Now I'd like to integrate Cypress in my CI/CD but I'm unsure on how to tell Cypress to visit the staging url instead of the local one.

Any idea?

```
it('The body of the page is in viewport', function() {
    cy.visit(
      'http://mylocalurltovisit.local.com.au:8666/foo'
    );
    let initialPosition;
    const body = cy.get('body');
    body.should('have.class', 'pdfView');
    cy.get('.body-wrapper').should($el => {
      initialPosition = $el.position();
      expect(initialPosition.top).equal(0);
      expect(initialPosition.left).equal(0);
    });
  });
```

I'd like for the visit url to automatically switch to say the staging one (which could be http://staging.com.au/foo) on the CI environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an environment variable, but instead of putting it in the config file, pass it in the CI command that starts Cypress, e.g

```
cypress run --env TARGET=local
cypress run --env TARGET=staging
```

In the test, you can assign the correct url (once only), using a `before()`.

```js
describe('...', () => {

  let url;

  before(function() {
    url = {
      local: 'http://...',
      staging: 'http://...'
    }[Cypress.env('TARGET')];
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to try creating the two different `url's` for `local and staging` sites as below in the `cypress.json` file.

```
{
    "env": {
        "project1_user": "admin",
        "project1_password": "password",
        "localSite" : {
            "url" : "http://mylocalurltovisit.local.com.au:8666/foo"            
        },
        "stagingSite" : {
            "url" : "http://staging.com.au/foo"

        }

    }
}
```

Then receive the urls to `const` inside the test;

```
const localUrl = Cypress.env('localSite').url;
const stagingUrl = Cypress.env('stagingSite').url;
```

You can call in `beforeEach` or use directly inside the test. Same way you can use for staging site a well.

```
beforeEach( function() {
    cy.visit(localUrl + '/somelogin.php' );

} );
```